# Sidekiq Stats mysteriously reset

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, sidekiq

We are in the process of migrating from Heroku to AWS, and I am noticing the Sidekiq stats mysteriously resetting for no apparent reason.

This is happening in several different applications that are connected to the same Redis instance, each with its own `namespace` set in `initializers/sidekiq.rb`.

The stats reset across all of the Sidekiq counters at the same time.  It seems like perhaps we are momentarily dropping the Redis connection, but that is just wild conjecture and at any rate I'm not sure how to mitigate it.

Is this a common problem?  Is there a setting I can tweak?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Someone is running the FLUSHDB or FLUSHALL command and clearing out data in Redis.  Perhaps one of the apps when it starts.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Mike.  Would calling `Sidekiq::Stats.new.reset` in one of the apps clear out the stats in all of the apps if they are using the same Redis but with different namespaces?

Comment: Or are there any popular gems that are known to call this under the hood?

Comment: No and not a chance.  No gem should ever reset your data.

Comment: Thanks, still trying to find the culprit.  If we are using the same Redis for caching, perhaps `Rails.cache.clear` is flushing everything across multiple namespaces?

Comment: that would do it. don't use namespaces. http://www.mikeperham.com/2015/09/24/storing-data-with-redis/

Comment: Thank you!  I'll see what I can do on my end and report back